Conditional typing is not working properly with boolean generic
I've got a very minimal TS code
function fnc<B extends boolean>(b: B){

  type C = B extends true ? number : string

  const isTrue : C = b ? 1 : "1" 

  // A lots of other definitions using C
  // ...

}

which raises
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'C'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'C'.

Playground
What's wrong with this code? It looks like if B extends true was false for it...
If I use const isTrue : C = (b ? 1 : "1") as C , no error appears, but I need to indicate it everywhere...
Thanks!

But your second link shows the same error...

Both playgrounds giving the same error. However, Try const isTrue: C = (b ? 1 : "1") as C;

We need to store the result of the ternary operation to be treated as type C.
modified-playground

@SharadPaul "store the result"? You're just asserting it, and you could write (b ? "1" : 1) as C and the same lack of error happens, even though it's completely wrong. Maybe I'm just misinterpreting the comment, but it seems misleading.

You are right @jcalz. Thanks for correction

@emonier, the issue is that TS does not do control flow analysis with generic type parameters in TS5.7 and below. It's ms/TS#33912, more or less. This will be at least somewhat addressed in TS5.8, but only for return types, and only of a particular form. When TS5.8 comes out you can change your code to something like this approach which is close to what you're doing. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

I don't think this is something that Typescript can do.
I think there are two problems here. The first is that B extends boolean does not imply that B will be either true or false; it can also just be boolean (each type is its own subtype, too), in which case it's clear that the expression b ? 1 : "1" must have type number|string.
The second problem is that Typescript doesn't seem to reduce conditional expressions based on the restriction of the boolean parameter. For example:
function f(b: true): number {
  return b ? 1 : "a";
}

Produces error: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
